# React render array to add to a list - simple return not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've created a simple object

```
const customer = { name : "foo", phone : "519-500-5000", orders : { crust: "normal", toppings :  ["Cheese", "Bacon"]} }
```

it holds a internal object called "orders" that has also has an array of toppings, in these case "Cheese" and "Bacon".

I've extracted the array out and passed it into a render toppings function

```
 renderToppings (toppings) {
    console.log("render Toppings: ", toppings) // Renders the whole array of toppings, good.
    toppings.forEach(function (topping) {
        //return (
        //    <li> {topping} </li>
        //)
        console.log("each Topping: ", topping) // This DOES render each topping separately as expected. 
    });
}
```

I created a list that has other values, then I eventually called my render method (which is within the same class)

```
{this.renderToppings (PizzaToppings)}
```

the console log does return the values I was expecting. But when I uncomment out the return, it doesn't do the console nor does it print the the toppings.

What am I missing here? Sorry if this is all sloppy, I'm new to react.

Comment: `return` returns from the function; nothing after it will execute, which is why your `console.log` isn't happened. Also, you're not returning anything from `renderToppings`; you probably want to do something like `return toppings.map` rather than `toppings.forEach`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't returning to anything. The return value of a `forEach()` callback is not used.

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead to generate an array of your elements and return that

```
return toppings.map(function (topping) {
    return (
        <li> {topping} </li>
    );
});
```

Demo

```js
class Pizza extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var toppings = ['cheese', 'sausage', 'never pineapple'];
    var elements = toppings.map(topping => {
      return ( 
        <li> 
          {topping} 
        </li>
      );
    });

    return ( 
      <ul id = "toppings">
        {elements}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Pizza /> ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a forEach only calls a given method on each item of the array and does nothing with the return value.

Use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead, map returns a new array. It also calls a method on each item in the array but allows you to return a new value for each item it iterates.

```
renderToppings (toppings) {
    toppings.map(function (topping) {
        return (
            <li> {topping} </li>
        )
    });
}
```

Would work in your case

Comment: @mhodges You are right. I should have commented instead, I have updated my answer and hope to have made my response a bit more informative for OP and future readers

Answer (score 3):

forEach doesn't return anything(returns undefined), you need to use map function

```
renderToppings (toppings) {

    return toppings.map((topping) => {
        return (
            <li> {topping} </li>
        )

    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The callback in .forEach modifies the original array, but for React to render the element you should create a new array with .map

Comment: forEach does not modify an array, it simply calls the passed function for each element in the array.